# block spam servers from htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-analytics, spam-prevention

I can`t block some spam servers, I see them all the time in google analytics ... and drive me nuts :)

I tried blocking them in .htaccess:

```
## SITE REFERRER BANNING
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} seo-services-with-results.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} seo-services-with-results.com
RewriteRule .* - [F]

## SITE REFERRER BANNING
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} better-seo-promotion.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} better-seo-promotion.com
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

but they still appear in google analytics. It seems to access a page that is not in my server:  **/h/6001432.html**

I have tried other method like (https://botcrawl.com/better-seo-promotion-com/) creating a Campaign Referral Path Filter .... but the same problem.

Is there a way i can stop spamming me those sites????

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the filters you have on this view?

Comment: Have you tried blocking `/h/6001432.html` as well?  Note that you can block the server from getting anything useful back, but the traffic will get to you anyway.  The only way to prevent them form reaching your site, is if you have a firewall (search for WAF), or some other device in front of your apache to block them.